# How to read ElasticSearch Snapshot file in S3?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, backup, snapshot

I am taking ElasticSearch snapshot from ElasticSearch live server to s3 and creating a replica of this in another Elasticsearch for analysis, instead of loading back to Elasticsearch how can I read data directly from S3?

Comment: are you storing snapshot in s3 bucket?

Comment: Restore the snapshot from S3 onto the other Elasticsearch cluster

Comment: @vipulprajapati yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapshots that you will create with according Elasticsearch [API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) are only should be used for restoring to other **Elasticsearch** clusters.

Physically those files are just binary files with some specific format, which makes them hard to read and analyse apart from using them as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I ended up sending data from logstash to s3 using the output plugin.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-s3.html

Hope this helps.